# Iterating through nested arrays / dictionaries for a single response rather than multiple responses

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, discord

This is my first post here - so forgive me for any errors.

Basically - I'm working with `disnake` / `python` as well as `json` and the `requests` module trying to parse JSON data from an API.

I've gotten pretty far along with it - but am currently stuck on returning nested dictionaries / arrays back as a SINGLE message rather than a 12-part message.

For example:

Here's the API response I'm working with:

```json
[
    {
        "sector": "Materials",
        "changesPercentage": "1.6493%"
    },
    {
        "sector": "Communication Services",
        "changesPercentage": "-0.0918%"
    },
    {
        "sector": "Consumer Cyclical",
        "changesPercentage": "0.3315%"
    },
    {
        "sector": "Consumer Defensive",
        "changesPercentage": "-0.0073%"
    },
    {
        "sector": "Consumer Goods",
        "changesPercentage": "-3.4825%"
    },
    {
        "sector": "Energy",
        "changesPercentage": "2.1286%"
    },
    {
        "sector": "Financials",
        "changesPercentage": "0.6245%"
    },
    {
        "sector": "Health Care",
        "changesPercentage": "-1.1625%"
    },
    {
        "sector": "Industrials",
        "changesPercentage": "1.3746%"
    },
    {
        "sector": "Real Estate",
        "changesPercentage": "0.7590%"
    },
    {
        "sector": "Information Technology",
        "changesPercentage": "0.9884%"
    },
    {
        "sector": "Utilities",
        "changesPercentage": "0.9104%"
    }
]
```

The command is: `!sectorweight SPY`.

The **PROBLEM** is that when I call the command from discord - it returns 10 messages instead of just the one message with all of the data:

```
Charlies Vids — Today at 10:04 AM
!sectorweight SPY
FUDSTOP Educator
BOT
 — Today at 10:04 AM
('Real Estate', '2.53%')
('Consumer Cyclical', '12.43%')
('Basic Materials', '2.34%')
('Consumer Defensive', '6.4%')
('Technology', '23.44%')
('Communication Services', '11.18%')
('Financial Services', '14.41%')
('Utilities', '2.64%')
('Industrials', '9.05%')
('Energy', '2.68%')
('Healthcare', '12.89%')
```

The above response comes in line by line rather than as a whole response.

Here's the code I currently have for it:

```py
@bot.command()
async def sectorweight(ctx, etf):
    r = requests.get(url=f"https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/etf-sector-weightings/{etf}?apikey={apikey}")
    data = r.json()
    for items in data:
        sector = items.get('sector')
        weight = items.get('weightPercentage')
        await ctx.send(f"{sector, weight}")
```

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: How to return the response as a single message rather than 10 separated messages

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `await ctx.send('\n'.join(f"{i['sector']}, {i['weightPercentage']}" for i in data))`? Imports: [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Comment: Don't duplicate your tags in your title

Answer (score 1):

The code you have now includes the `send` method inside your for loop. This means it will send a message at each iteration, or loop. The way you'd send only one message would be to create a single string, add all the data to it in the for loop, then send that instead. It might look something like this:

```py
data = r.json()
msg = []
for items in data:
    sector = items.get('sector')
    weight = items.get('weightPercentage')
    msg.append(f"{sector, weight}")

msg = '\n'.join(msg)
await ctx.send(msg)
```